# Formatting data in dropdown box pulled from db?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following snippet of code:

```
<li>
    <label>Engine Size:</label>
    <select name="engine">
        <?php
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT BikeEngine FROM bikes "
                . "ORDER BY BikeEngine ASC");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            echo "<option>" . $row['BikeEngine'] . "cc" . "</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</li>
```

My main issue is that the engine size is stored as an int in the database field but I want to add the cc on the end in the dropdown box as a suffix, but when the query is ran, it searches for say 1500cc and returns no results because it is stored as 1500 in the database field.

I was wondering how I'd go about resolving this?

Model:

```
public function searchBikes($brand, $engine)
{
    if ($engine=='Any' || $brandString=='Any')
    {
        $this->db->select('BikeEngine');
        $this->db->select('BikeMake');
        $query = $this->db->get('bikes');
    }

    else
    {
        $this->db->like('BikeEngine', $engine);
        $this->db->like('BikeMake', $brand);
    }

    $query = $this->db->get('bikes');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Controller:

```
function search() {
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url')); //without this form will not display

if ($this->input->post())
{
    $brand = $this->input->post('brand');
    $engine = $this->input->post('engine');
    $this->load->model("mbikes");
    $data['results'] = $this->mbikes->searchBikes($brand, $engine);
    $this->load->view('searchresults.php', $data);
} 
else 
{
    $this->load->view('search.php'); //display success view
}
}
```

Comment: @LorenzMeyer that comment was made about another post - not sure how it ended up on this one.

Answer (score 3):

An options value can be different from its display:

```
echo "<option value=". $row['BikeEngine'] .">" . $row['BikeEngine'] . "cc" . "</option>";
```

Comment: I see. Since I am pulling options in the dropdown from the database, is it possible to add an `Any` option that will return all products with any engine size rather than forcing the user to search for specifics?

Comment: @user3554442 It sure is, but i would have to see the php that make the search to give an exact answer. Basically you would create the <option value="any">Any Engine</option> element above the while loop. Then in the form handleing code check if the value is 'any' or a number, and handle accordingly

Comment: well, using that info, i would guess at if($engine=='any'){$this->db->all}else{$this->db->like('BikeEngine', $engine)} Though i dont use codeignitor so i dont know what the syntax for select all is

Comment: Please edit your question to show the full code, as its hard to work out from a few snippets in comments

Comment: @user3554442 Looks ok at first glance. Have you checked its not an upper/lowercase issue. Eg you check for 'Any' but you might be sending 'any'//lowercase A